# regex email explanation

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm new to regex and not sure how each part of the below breaks down to testing for email, especially the `!` at beginning and the `._%+0-`

```
!/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(values.email)
```

Comment: The first `!` character is JavaScript's _NOT_ operator.

Comment: plot it into [http://regexr.com/](http://regexr.com/) and open the explain tab in the bottom of the page.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/bgURzi/1